# A women's accessory...what's the word?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the accessory that is like a net that is worn by women on the head and that comes all the way till the eyes... it is worn on formal occasions and its is quite old fashioned (IMHO).
It is not used to hold the hair on anything I think. Sometimes I have seen that it comes attached to the bonnet...

Update 1: I remember finding the word in the dictionary once.

Comment: One of those rare occasions a questioner gives a precise and accurate description of something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is called a *birdcage veil*.

You can see a bunch of examples on [Etsy](http://www.etsy.com/search_results.php?search_type=all&includes%5B0%5D=materials&page=1&q=bird+cage+veil).

Comment: 'birdcage' is often left out especially in Western fashion/non-Islamic contexts.

Comment: hmm....I thought a veil was always a fabric.

Comment: @SurajNayak, no, not always; for example, expression *[take the veil](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+the+veil)* (to take vows) involves neither netting nor fabric

Comment: @SurajNayak: a [wedding veil](http://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&q=wedding+veil) is usually not a fabric, but a kind of netting that obscures.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is what you envisioned, it's a ***"veil"*** and is still used by high-fashion hat wearers:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... ya.. that is what I had in mind...